# Sword Fiona vs Hammer Fiona

Tags: vindictus

Traversing the internet, I have found many answers saying "Hammer Fiona is the best, after enchanting she does tons of damage" and the likes. But isn't a big part of Fiona's play-style blocking and distracting the boss for your team? And in that case wouldn't Sword Fiona be better after enchanting because the sword would be super fast as well, and you can finish combos quickly and still get a block in on the boss, in time?

I feel like all the "hammer fiona, dmg dmg dmg, lel" answers I've seen do not take into account playing with a sword or they may solo often, and thus want more damage.

My Fiona is only level 20 right now, so maybe I don't realize which is better, thanks to anyone who answers this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of boils down to preference, but basically Fiona is a "Spike Damage" character. she comes no where close to the DPS capabilities of someone like Lann, but when she gets her combo off (a challenge in itself) the damage output surpasses most characters in the game.

THe main difference between hammer and sword is the speed. Hammer is much stronger yes, but it is also very slow. Its near impossible to get her fully charged smash on a boss without it being stunned first. On the flip side, however, it's relatively easy to get her sword kick off.

Most of those reviews you've been reading probably mostly talk about end game Fiona, where all there really is to do is raids, damage matters most here. The quicker the group can melt the boss the better, so most everyone rolls for highest damage output.

Tanking/blocking doesnt matter on the weapon chosen, but the shield. Most Fionas (especially raid ones) will choose heavy shield because its capable of withstanding much more pain), but once your going through the story, stick with small shield for the counterattack and maneuverability

When you unlock the hammer (level 22 if I remember correctly) do a few missions with it yourself and see how you like it.

Comment: Before I begin it's level 12 when you get it. Anyways, I don't exactly feel like this answers my question. You said that in higher levels especially, it is more about dealing damage then trying to block. So wouldn't swords be better to get off combos easier before getting smashed in the face?

Comment: I haven't played in a while (secondary weapons were lvl 22) and I said in the first part of my answer it boils down to preference. both the hammer and sword are capable of high damage spikes, but the hammer is capable of much more. In raids when the boss is stunned, being grappled by a Karok, or some environmental hazard locking the boss... the output from a hammer will far surpass that of a sword.

Comment: alright! That sums it up, I think I'll switch over to hammer once I get leveled enough to equip the good ones I picked up from my main then.